# Get a number of possible combinations Python

Tags: python, combinations

How do I get a number of the possible **combinations** knowing the number of characters used in generating the combinations and a range of lengths.

To get all **permutations** i would use:

```
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
minLen = 1
maxLen = 3

total = 0
for i in range(minLen,maxLen+1):
    total += len(chars)**i
```

How would I do this for **combinations**? When repetition is **not** allowed.

I'm sure there's a mathematical formula to do this but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I realised that code might not be readable so here's an explenation:

It's pretty obvious what the variables are: minimum combination length, maximum, used characters...

The for loop goes from 1 to 3 and each time it adds this to the `total`: length of characters (len(chars)) to the power of i (the current iteration's length).

This is a basic way of calculating permutations.

Comment: I'm probably completely underestimating what you're trying to do here- but are you thinking of the number of [k-combinations] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). If so, this question is probably a duplicate. Best.

Comment: I am. I'm not sure on how to implement this programmatically (so I'm asking here) :)

Comment: [itertools permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) would seem to be your friend here.

Comment: You could do it just with nested for loops. In your example you can just have 3 nested for loops and brute force it.

Comment: I am working with hundreds of thousands of numbers. I don't think brute-forcing is a good idea.

Comment: @Tom You can flag it if you want, but none of the answers answer my question correctly. They are either too slow (such as len(list(itertools.combinations()))) or don't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but consider if you just want the number of combinations used the closed form solution from the answer linked to, rather than generating them all and counting the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you actually need a way to count the Binomial coefficient, right?

```
import math

def binomial_cooefficient(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    n_fac = math.factorial(n)
    k_fac = math.factorial(k)
    n_minus_k_fac = math.factorial(n - k)
    return n_fac/(k_fac*n_minus_k_fac)
```

This might not be the most optimal implementation, but it works :)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: For anyone who reaches this answer, there is a `math.comb` function now to calculate the binomial coefficient (n choose k).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for [scipy.misc.comb](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html) (which gives you the number of unique combinations of a binomial (of the form of *from N take X*):

```
>>> from scipy.misc import comb
>>> comb(10, 1) # Num of unique combinations of *from 10 take 1*
10.0
>>> comb(10, 2) # Num of unique combinations of *from 10 take 2*
45.0
```

And so on.. You can then get a nice reduce:

```
>>> total_len = 10
>>> min_size = 1
>>> max_size = 2
>>> reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + comb(total_len, x), range(min_size, max_size+1), 0)
55.0
```

The above `reduce` is the 1-liner functional equivalent of your for:

```
>>> total = 0
    for x in range(min_size, max_size+1):
        total += comb(total_len, x)
```

As a side note, if you use `comb(total_len, x, exact=True)` you will get the result as an integer rather than a float.